# jquery passing in direction to animate()

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, direction

I am getting the direction from the div click and a, trying to pass this into the animate function

```
var direction = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
var scrollAmount = 285;
$('#slider').animate({direction:'-=' + scrollAmount}, 'slow');
```

What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the animate function takes in CSS properties stating the final properties for the end of the animation. You can not pass direction that way. It sounds like you either want to set the left or scrollLeft amount and to change direction then you should look at the value of direction and either use -= or += depending on the way you want to go.

```
var sign;

if (direction == 'left') sign = '-=';
else sign = '+=';

$('#slider').animate({left:sign + scrollAmount}, 'slow');
```

Or if it is the property you are trying to pass

```
var prop = {};
prop[direction] = scrollAmount;
$('#slider').animate(prop, 'slow');
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use '-=' or '+=' operator, because zoom issues in chrome? Is there an "equivalent" call???

Answer (score 1):

There is no such property in `animate` called as direction hence the error. Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Edit as per comment

Then you should pass left or right in the css as the first parameter to animate

Example code from jQuery animate API documentation

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>   <style>
> div {
>   position:absolute;
>   background-color:#abc;
>   left:50px;
>   width:90px;
>   height:90px;
>   margin:5px;
> }
> </style>
>   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <button id="left">&laquo;</button> <button id="right">&raquo;</button>
> <div class="block"></div>
>
> <script>
> $("#right").click(function(){
>   $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
> });
>
> $("#left").click(function(){
>   $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
> });
>
> </script>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: I am trying to pass in the direction either 'left' or 'right'